# Error - Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.'

Tags: vb.net

Please help in below code error shows:

> Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

```
Dim constring As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &
Application.StartupPath & "\db_billing.accdb;Persist Security Info=True")

Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constring)
    Using cmdd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert into tlbitems values(@Estimate_Number,@Service_Procedure_Name,@Amount)", con)

        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estimate_Number", row.Cells("Serial_Number").Value)
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service_Procedure_Name", row.Cells("Service").Value)
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", row.Cells("Total").Value)


        con.Open()
        cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

    End Using
End Using
Next
    MessageBox.Show("Saved")
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a database error. Can you show the database structure? Also this is not C#. Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the columns names in your insert query like below:

```
Using cmdd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert into tlbitems(Estimate_Number, Service_Procedure_Name, Amount)  
values(@Estimate_Number,@Service_Procedure_Name,@Amount)", con)
```

This is just an example, you should put the correct column names from your table `tlbitems` defination.

Comment: hii i need to insert data from DataGridViewRow and hawing error with this code

Comment: Please try what I suggested in my answer. Do you see any difference between your query and mine?

Comment: Thanks for your support i have modified the code and issues resolved

Comment: Great. Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer